# Python list of dict parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of dict which I need to parse into a dict {A:[b,c]}.

```
iam_profile_association = [{'AssociationId': 'iip-assoc-08c2998aabf8ad37e', 'InstanceId': 'i-078cf2f285a2bb4d3', 'IamInstanceProfile': {'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam:::instance-profile/STANDARD-SSM-INSTANCEPROFILE-us-east-1', 'Id': 'AIPAZTOKUMIFDJ4VGT2FP'}, 'State': 'associated'}, {'AssociationId': 'iip-assoc-0afc8368072fa1d7e', 'InstanceId': 'i-076d4c961d800ba18', 'IamInstanceProfile': {'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam:::instance-profile/STANDARD-SSM-INSTANCEPROFILE-us-east-1', 'Id': 'AIPAZTOKUMIFDJ4VGT2FP'}, 'State': 'associated'}, {'AssociationId': 'iip-assoc-0c46d1f23de061e98', 'InstanceId': 'i-0942731f00ebd33e1', 'IamInstanceProfile': {'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam:::instance-profile/STANDARD-SSM-INSTANCEPROFILE-us-east-1', 'Id': 'AIPAZTOKUMIFDJ4VGT2FP'}, 'State': 'associated'}]

                    iam_dict = {}
                    for iam_assoc in iam_profile_association:
                        
                        iam_dict[iam_assoc['InstanceId']] = [iam_assoc['AssociationId'],iam_assoc['IamInstanceProfile']['Arn']]
                        
                        print (iam_dict)
```

iam_dict just prints the first value :

```
{'i-078cf2f285a2bb4d3': ['iip-assoc-08c2998aabf8ad37e', 'arn:aws:iam::660239311370:instance-profile/STANDARD-SSM-INSTANCEPROFILE-us-east-1']}
```

Can someone help me in this? I would like to store all the values in this dict format.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? Paste your code in then select the code lines then click on  the `{}` button to apply the correct tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` is inside the for loop, move it outside (tab it in)

```
iam_dict = {}
for iam_assoc in iam_profile_association:

    iam_dict[iam_assoc['InstanceId']] = ...........
                        
print (iam_dict)
```

It's tricky to work out more than that from what you are asking. But this would be a good start.